# Capacitor iOS App doesn't scale to full height

Tags: ios, capacitor

I've created an app based on capacitor. Everything runs fine on Android. But on iOS, the capacitor WebView doesn't fill the available height.
The following screenshot illustrates the issue. There, I put a white box over the area where the WebView is located. In the WebView, everything works as expected. While debugging the app via Xcode, the following information is returned by the WebView's frame:

```
CGRect? (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 320, height = 480))
```

I already tried to resize that frame, but the black areas on the top and bottom remain.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Seems .. you don't have a LaunchScreen (SplashScreen). Check this: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/launch-screen/ and this https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-icons-splash-screens-launch-images-to-capacitor-projects/

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the issue :-)
Setting the Launch Screen File in the Info.plist fixed it. I've no idea why this was empty. It's a new Capacitor project.

Answer (score 2):

i don't have much knowledge about capacitor but in Ionic/coredova app `viewport-fit=cover` use to remove white space

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">
```

I have found this solution from below link:
[Remove White space](https://codeburst.io/making-ionic-cordova-app-compatible-for-iphone-x-c84d62b61aa9)

Comment: Thanks, but the viewport-fit was already set to that value.